# Serve external folder

Tags: c#, .net-core

How can I serve a folder other than `wwwroot` using an absolute path?  The folder is on a different drive on my local machine.  I am getting this error:

> 'The path in 'value' must start with '/'.'

Here is my `Starup.cs` `Configure()`

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
        
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"E:\path\to\folder\"),
        RequestPath = new PathString("\\stuff")
    });
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: I _think_ your problem is that it should be `/stuff` not `\\stuff`.

Comment: Whoa -- I didn't realize I \\ is an escape character in the comments. You shouldn't be using `\\` at all.

Comment: You use `/` instead. .NET Core has fully embraced the `/` as the universal separator for better compatibility against Mac and Linux targets.

Comment: Do not put editorial comments into posts. Posts should include strictly the facts. If you want to discuss things, you can put them in a question on meta.stackoverflow.com. Also do not put tags in the title. I've edited your question to correct these mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, is the question perfect, now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequestPath` refers to the path to serve the content from in the application, so it needs to start with a `/`:

```
RequestPath = new PathString("/stuff")
```